# Unable to parse json data from ajax in flask

Tags: python, json, ajax, flask

I am trying to pass data from ajax to routes.py in flask through json. I have sometimes made it pop up a dialog box with the actual data, but I am unable to parse the data or have it appear on a webpage itself..(I eventually need to have this data manipulate sql db but for now I am just trying to be able to manipulate the data).

routes.py

```
@app.route("/post", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post():
    data = request.get_json()
    jsonify(data=data)
    x = request.json['index']

    return render_template('post.html', x=x)
```

request.json['index'] does not work and throws TypeError: 'NoneType'

if I return jsonify(data=data) instead of have it before the return, I can see the data in a dialog window when I go to localhost:5000/post

index.html

```
<script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
                update: function(event, ui) {
                    var postData = $(this).sortable('serialize');



                }
            });
        });

        function postSave() {$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
                        console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).attr('id') );


                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/post',
                            data: JSON.stringify({ "index" : index, "id" : $( this ).attr('id') } ),
                            type: 'POST',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                            }

                         });
                         var url = "/post";
                         $(location).attr('href',url);

                        });
            }



        </script>
```

post.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- simply be able to parse through the data and print it here for testing purposes -->
</body>
</html>
```

all help is greatly appreciated, I am pulling my hair out as we speak :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `post` route has been configured to handle both `GET` and `POST` requests, but you don't distinguish between `GET` and `POST` requests. Since there is no distinction between the two type of requests if your **browser sent off a GET request to your post route on your flask server there will be no `JSON` data in your request.** A simple conditional like the following: `if flask.request.method == 'POST':` can be used to distinguish between the two types of requests. With that being said, maybe you could try out something like the following:

```
  @app.route('/post', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
      def post():
          if request.method == "POST":
              req_data = request.get_json()
              x = req_data['index']
              return render_template('post.html', x=x)
           else: # GET request
              # handle as you see fit probably want to render a page 
              # with inputs for a user to fill out 
              return render_template(<page_you_wish_to_render>)
```

If this doesn't work could you please print out `req_data`? So we can see what the request looks like as it might be invalid `JSON`.

Also, your `ajax` call looks a little off, maybe you could edit just the Ajax part to something like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : "{{url_for('post')}}",
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    data : {'index':index}
});
```

Lastly, I would put a `debugger` statement right before you send off your ajax request to make sure the request is correct.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your post and your edits. I really appreciate it. When I use the code you provided I get "Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL." That is why I originally had the GET in there, but that just pulls the NoneType error. Any other ideas? all appreciated greatly, thank you!

Comment: I am unable to print req_data unless I add 'GET', it then gives me the error: TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

Comment: Yes, that is because we were only supporting POST requests I have edited my answer to support GET requests as well for you. You've to distinguish between the type of requests you're receiving so you can respond appropriately. Hopefully that makes sense